# how to tell if a View is not being used in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

is there a way to tell if a View is not being used by anything in MYSQL ? like there is the schema_unused_indexes view to find unused indexes, is there anything similar or any other way to tell if a View is being utilized via other objects etc.

thx

Comment: It's not 100% what you mean by "used". Do you mean if it's being actually called (i.e. people are running queries on it, in which case you'd need to switch on logging), or do you mean whether other code objects (e.g. other view or stored procedures) have a dependency on it?

Comment: You could try the Hammer Approach! Rename it, so you can get it back quickly,  and wait to see if anybody SCREAMS.... or just watch the error log

Comment: both of those actually, what logging would need to be enabled for monitoring that ? yes ive looked at taking it offline as well . just wondering what would be best way to get that detail for this issue or in the future